# Windows Automation via Console Application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winapi, console, automation, low-level-api

I'm a novice programmer and I've run across a problem in creating a Console Application to automate a simple mathematical application.

**The requirements of the Console is it must use low-level WinAPI call to automate, it cannot make use of Reflection or any other 3rd party libraries, including MS Visual Studio UI/Testing automation assemblies. All automation must be performed by wrapping the Executable application and automating it as a standalone application at runtime using the WinAPI functions defined in user32.dll.**

*Which brings me to my question, what does all of that mean? Can I not build the console app in Visual Studio? Can someone explain low-level WinAPI? Wrapping the app and automating as standalone? It's just something I've never done and also is this something that is useful in the workplace in today's development world?*

Any advice and support is appreciated, not looking for code answers but just explanations of HOW, WHERE, WHAT, and WHY? Basically explain this to me in the SIMPLEST terms for a beginner programmer who mostly uses Visual Studio.

Comment: The wording of that sounds like a very specific and bizare college/university assignment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use WinAPI function calls for automating your mathematical application and not use any readily available tools (like QTP and other Test Automation tools). You can build the application in Visual Studio in any language (C++/C#, etc), but must use WinApi functions only. So for example if the Mathematical application displays a window and accepts user input, your console application will use WinApi functions to automatically insert input in the relevant fields and click the OK or Cancel (or any other) button to navigate to the next screen and for all subsequent areas where the mathematical application waits for input from the user.

Comment: Thanks. I know understand and know where to go from here.

Comment: One more question, where can I find these functions? I checked MSDN and I've found hundreds of functions, but I don't see anything related to mathematical functions. Any points?

Comment: You will need to refer to the WinApi functions : [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff818516(v=vs.85).aspx) . The Functional requirement document of your Mathematical Application will tell you about the inputs accepted in the Mathematical Application and the outputs. Your Console Application will insert these inputs programatically and record the outputs.