# Windows Form Automation in C++ using low level WinAPI Calls? Still don't know

Tags: winapi, console, automation

[Windows Automation via Console Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14151149/windows-automation-via-console-application/14151601#14151601)

This still doesn't answer my question. How do you do it? Because I have never programmed in C++ but I know Visual Basic.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, you get the handle of the window you wish to interact with.
`FindWindow` may well be your friend here. In some instances, you may need to use the `EnumChildWindows` function. An example of this would be using `FindWindow` to get a handle to the main window of an instance of `Notepad.exe`. After getting this handle, you could use `EnumChildWindows` to step through the list of child windows, one of which wil be the control that you type text into.

After this, you send messages to it. If you need to simulate keystrokes/mouse events, you should use the appropriate window handle and the function `SendInput`.

In the instance that you wish to simulate a button-press, you can use `SendInput` to position the mouse over the button (whose window handle you'll need to get, before getting its size and position). You can get the button's ID by using Spy++ or a free alternative. - Another alternative involves simply sending a WM_COMMAND message to the button's owner, using the same arguments that would be sent when clicking on it manually - this approach saves you the effort of locating and sizing the button before positioning the mouse and setting the left-button down and finally, setting the button up again.

An exerpt of a program that uses the first method may look like this. Bear in mind that I've already obtained a handle to the parent window and determined the size and location of the playing area. (the code is from a bot that played XP's Minesweeper game)

```
if (!bombHere)
{
  GetClickPos(iFinalX0ffset, iFinalY0ffset, boardPos.left, boardPos.top, &pClick, i, j);
  pClick.x = pClick.x * 65536.0f / iScreenW;
  pClick.y = pClick.y * 65536.0f / iScreenH;
  mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, pClick.x, pClick.y, 0, 0);
  // since square is both unsolved and safe, left click it once
  mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);

  if (moveDelay)
      Sleep(moveDelay);
}
```